# EffDated branches on policyPeriod and saving arrays

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I have an array that is saved on the policyPeriod level right now called listOfAdditionalInsured. This list is display on one of the pages in the UI in PC.

The issue that I am having is that each time there is a policy change it will erase the data on that list because it's on the policyPeriod level. I see other arrays in PolicyPeriod that are not deleted during policy change and will appear fine. They look like they are effdated entities.

I am new to this so I am trying to figure out how to keep an array on the policyPeriod level but let it be editable during a change. I have tried putting it on the Policy level but it will change the array for all the transactions if I do it that way. I want each transaction to be able to edit the list in its own way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your array entity is an Effective Dated entity and that the effDatedBrachType is PolicyPeriod. Take a look at how PolicyContactRole is implemented and try to do the same.

[image]